# javascript scrollbars without mousewheel support

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some child divs that may or may not be scrollable. I would like for scrollbars to appear if it is scrollable. However I would like these bars to be usable only with click and drag and for the mousewheel to scroll the parent div. I've been looking at some jquery scrollbar plugins but they all support mousewheel and will allow control of the parent only when the scroll limit of the child has been reached. Does anyone know of a jquery (or other) plugin that will support this behaviour?

Any help greatly appreciated
C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that adding a mousewheel event, and preventing the default behaviour should work, i.

```
$('#child').on('mousewheel', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

If you use:

```
overflow:auto;
```

the scrollbars will only appear when needed.

See this jsFiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/956hm6j2/).

I hope that this helps.